# RestTemplate encoding parameter with +

Tags: encoding, parameters, uri, resttemplate

I've been struggling to properly encode a parameter like this:

```
filter=startDate eq "2020-08-21T00:00:00+04:30"
```

So it's encoded like this:

```
filter=startDate%20eq%20%222020-08-21T00:00:00%2B04:30%22
```

But I get this:

```
filter=startDate%20eq%20%222020-08-21T00:00:00+4:30%22
```

Which obviously is wrong, I need the + sign encoded as well.

The code looks like this.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder;
URI uri;
uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).build(id);
builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(uri);

if (filter != null) {
  builder.queryParam("filter", filter);
}

builder.build(false).toUriString();
```

The full URL should look like this:

```
https://example.com/object/id?filter=startDate%20eq%20%222020-08-21T00:00:00%2B04:30%22
```

Tried this solution without luck: [RestTemplate.exchange() does not encode '+'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676060/resttemplate-exchange-does-not-encode)

Any idea?

**Update:**
Saw this promising answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56291853/198108 but can't seem to make it work. I tried to add it like this in my class that extends OAuth2RestTemplate:

```
HttpClient httpClient =
        CustomHttpClientBuilder.create().setMaxConnTotal(5_000).setMaxConnPerRoute(2_500).build();
    // Allow to log the response body and also return it to the caller.
    setRequestFactory(
        new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient)));
```

But the code is never executed.

Comment: This may not be a solution to your problem, but you could consider a different encoding. Like just saving the milliseconds or seconds since epoch. That way you would not have any + signs to encode

Comment: can you elaborate who you mean by "encoded like" and "get this".  Just check with online URL encoders. it can encode and decode without any issue of not encoding plus sign

Comment: Do you mean RestTemplate is wrongly encoding

Comment: In this specific case, yes